# Problem with DateTime.TryParseExact

Tags: vb.net

Could someone tell me what is wrong with this code please.

```
Public Shared Function TestDateTime() As String
    Dim Result As String = ""

    Dim Test As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParseExact("20110331_153103", "yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, Test) Then
        Result = "Valid DateTime"

    Else
        Result = "Not a valid DateTime"

    End If

    Return Result
End Function
```

I'm sure it should return "Valid DateTime" but it will not whatever parameters I pass for the culture and datetimestyle

Thanks.

Comment: Try it with 20110331_033103 and if it works, then you'll know the problem is related to 24 vs. 12-hour time. But that's probably not the problem. That is just the first thing I thought of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, try `..._HHmmss'.

Comment: Yep, thats the answer. Just posted the questions and saw what it was. Typical! Thanks for your time Anton.